# Customizing view.phtml template

Tags: template

Hello I would like to make changes in my Magento template product listing page right now it displays the image only and i want to write the text after the image.

I tried to edit in `view.php` file but its not working for me.

Here i am attaching the picture what exactly i want.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `app/design/frontend/{Package}/{your-theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` you find: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>`  and the heart image is located here.

So to customise it you go to `app/design/frontend/{Package}/{your-theme}/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml`then add your text as somthing like this `<?php echo $this->__('your text here');?>` . so not directly in view.phtml

Comment: Hello Thank you for your response but i already did this thing.

You can find it here below 
<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li> 
Still its not showing.

Comment: Please, provide the path of the file and the code.

Comment: The Path of the file is app/design/frontend/{Package}/{your-theme}/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml
The Code is :-
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_wishlistSubmitUrl = $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>

<ul class="add-to-links">
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>